# reserved time (calendar) gives back bad values.

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have a problem with getting data from database which dates are booked.

example booked hours are: 08:00:00 and 10:00:00 and I want to show free hours which are 13:00:00 and 15:00:00

but it gives me 10:00  13:00  15:00   08:00   10:00   15:00 as a free time.

```
$ch = $db->execute("SELECT `time` FROM `calendar` WHERE `date` = '2015-01-08'");
while(list($time) = $db->fetch($ch)) {


if($time != "08:00:00") { echo"<option value=\"08:00\">08:00</option>"; }
if($time != "10:00:00") { echo"<option value=\"10:00\">10:00</option>"; }
if($time != "13:00:00") { echo"<option value=\"13:00\">13:00</option>"; }
if($time != "15:00:00") { echo"<option value=\"15:00\">15:00</option>"; }

}
```

Comment: did the suggestion help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be a logic issue?
It looks like your query brings back all the times for that date.
So if the first value it returns is `08:00:00` it will `echo` on all other 3 ifs.

```
 echo"<option value=\"10:00\">10:00</option>";
 echo"<option value=\"13:00\">13:00</option>";
 echo"<option value=\"15:00\">15:00</option>";
```

but it will execute the same logic for all returned `times`, hence why you are seeing the duplicate times.

You could try and add all the `options` to a array. Then when looping through the returned values, you remove the item from the array if it is equal to the returned value.
This way you end up with only the `free times`.

**This is some pseudo code to give you the idea of a possible solution**

```
timeArray = [08:00, 10:00, 13:00, 15:00]


$ch = $db->execute("SELECT `time` FROM `calendar` WHERE `date` = '2015-01-08'");
while(list($time) = $db->fetch($ch)) {

    //If item is found, remove it from 'free time array'
    found = find_in_array(timeArray, returnedTime)
    if (found > 0) {
        remove_item_from_array( timeArray, found )
    }

}
```

timeArray should now contain only ( 13:00, 15:00 )

Comment: because you can book uniq time in a day. lets say 08:00:00, so no one else will do.  1 time for 1 client to visit.

Comment: so whats wrong. print_r gives me two array( ) 

array ( [0]=>'08:00:00', [time]=>'08:00:00')
array ( [0]=>'10:00:00', [time]=>'10:00:00')

Comment: Yes you are 100% correct. But you are in a `While` loop and so you are doing the same thing for each returned value. so in this case `08:00` and `10:00`.
You could be better of bringing back all the values in a list. Then loop through that list and eliminate the `options` found.